# Saving a "craft-linkfield" field via an entry form

Tags: craft3, custom-fieldtype, link

I'm editing an entry via an entry form as documented here:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html

How would I be able to save a link field that's using https://github.com/sebastian-lenz/craft-linkfield ?

I tried this:

```
<input id="website" type="text" name="fields[website]">
```

(where "website" is the handle of the link field) but that just throws a syntax error (in json_decode) at vendor/sebastianlenz/linkfield/src/fields/LinkField.php:112

It works fine for other  elements that use one of the built-in field types.

Is this even possible using the standard entries/save-entry endpoint? Or would I need to write a custom controller, and how so?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by inspecting the HTML for the entry edit form in the CP. This works:

```
<input id="fields-website-type" name="fields[website][type]" value="url" type="hidden">
<input id="fields-website-isCpFormData" name="fields[website][isCpFormData]" value="true" type="hidden">
<input id="website" type="text" name="fields[website][url]">
```